# When Python processes will kill

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, bigdata

I am using `multiprocessing` to process big `excel` files in a single process (For performance purposes).

```py
import multiprocessing
def process_file_callback(filepath: str) -> None:
    ''' process big excel file here '''

def main() -> None:
    for filepath in filepathes:
        process_instance = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_file_callback, args=(filepath,))
        process_instance.start()
```

For example, I am creating `200-500` processes. Now imagine scenario, that my system stops working (I mean, I typed `CTRL+C` in terminal). My `script` stops working, isn't it ? What about other processes ? They are killed as well ? (I mean which processes `excel` files).

Comment: unrelated, but you probably shouldn't be using 2-500 processes... there's no benefit to having more processes than cpu cores, and there's a pretty significant overhead per process. instead consider something like `Pool.map`

Comment: @Aaron We agree that 500 processes would probably be a ridiculous number of processes on a computer with say 4 physical cores. Where we disagree is your blanket statement "there's no benefit to having more processes than cpu cores." That may be true in most cases but not necessarily when the worker function has both significant CPU-intensive calculations and significant I/O.

Answer (score 0):

The child processes will not be cleaned up if the parent dies unexpectedly via a signal that is not handled (such as `kill -9`). Python uses the `atexit` module to handle cleanup of multiprocessing, and the cleanup handlers will only run properly if the program finishes normally or if `sys.exit()` is called (but not when `os._exit()` is called directly). Of note, when an exception occurs, and is not caught (like keyboardinterrupt) `sys.exit()` is called after printing the traceback. The default behavior for child processes at exit cleanup is to `join()` them. If they cannot proceed normally after the main process has encountered an exception, a deadlock may occur. If the main interpreter is force quit by the user, the children become zombies.

Comment: So, if `KeyboardInterrupt` exception is raised, child processes still continues working ?

But callback registered using `atexit` module starts working even `Exception` is raised. Is something wrong ?

Comment: @shzetb unfortunately the answer is complicated... the operating system is what handles signals. I can tell you that in a past project about 7 years ago I was struggling with zombie processes on macOS while developing some multiprocessing code. Any time I would ^C or an exception occurred, I'd get extra zombies. On the other hand, trying to come up with a quick example on windows here, It seems windows propagates signals to all children of a given process. You should do some testing to determine how your system will react. It's also good to explicitly handle signals with the `signal` module.